# Express the cosine of triple angle $3x$ in terms of cosines of $2x$ and $x$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that $$\cos{3x}=2\cos{2x}\cos{x}-\cos{x}$$

I've tried adding and subtracting $\cos{x}$ from $\cos{3x}$, like this: $$\cos{3x}+\cos{x}-\cos{x}$$ so I get that $$\cos{3x}+\cos{x}=2\cos{2x}\cos{x}$$ But I have no idea how these are equal.

Comment: Do you know the angle addition formulas? If so, hint: $\cos(3x) = \cos(2x+x)$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

$$\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$$

$$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

$$\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}=1-2\sin^2{x}\implies \sin^2{x}=\frac{1-\cos{2x}}2$$

With the above you're done.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$\cos(3x)=\cos(2x+x)=\cos(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)$$

and use the formula for $\sin(2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula, $\displaystyle\cos C+\cos D=\cdots$ on $\cos3x+cosx$

---

Alternatively,
 $$\cos3x+cosx=\cos(2x+x)+\cos(2x-x)=?$$

---

Alternatively use  [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)  $$2\cos2x\cos x=\cos(2x+x)+cos(2x-x)$$